# Creating a page where people can add ideas underneath (HTML/PHP)

Tags: php, html, forms

basically I want to add a system to my site where people are able to submit ideas via a form. Now I originally did it like this:

```
<form name="web_form" id="web_form" method="post" action="process-form-data.php">
        <p><label>Name: </label><input type="text" name="name" id="name" /></p>
        <p><label>Idea: </label><input type="text" name="idea" id="idea" maxlength="3000" height="400px" width="550px" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="s1″ id="s1″ value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Process form data then sends the info to a text file:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$idea = $_POST['idea'];
$fp = fopen("ideas.txt", "a");
$savestring = $name . "," . $idea . "n";
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
fclose($fp);
echo "<h1>You data has been saved in a text file!</h1>";
?>
```

However when including the .txt file on the original page, it comes out in a one line format like this:

> Name,Idea Sam,this is my ideanSam,this is my ideanSam,this is my idean

What is a better way of implementing this system for non web-savvy users?

All I want is a simple page where all ideas can be seen by everyone logged in.

Many thanks.

Comment: The best way is to use a database..

Comment: How do I include the database on a simple .php page?

Answer (score 1):

```
$savestring = $name . "," . $idea . "\n";
```

You missed a `\n`

Using a decent IDE with good configurations could highlight special chars with escapes. That help to find out such simple errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the content of the text file in the browser, it needs to be HTML compliant.  So, you need `<BR>` for each newline:

```
$savestring = $name . "," . $idea . "<br>";
```